# writing if/else statement as ternary operator

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I write this using a ternary operator?

```js
if (!$('#privacy_check').is(':checked')) {
  $('#privacy_check').css('outline-color', 'red');
  $('#privacy_check').css('outline-style', 'solid');
  $('#privacy_check').css('outline-width', 'thin');
} else {
  $('#privacy_check').css('outline-color', 'none');
  $('#privacy_check').css('outline-style', 'none');
  $('#privacy_check').css('outline-width', '0');
}
```

I have tried

```js
!$('#privacy_check').is(':checked') ? $('#privacy_check').css('outline-color', 'red'); $('#privacy_check').css('outline-style', 'solid');$('#privacy_check').css('outline-width', 'thin') :
$('#privacy_check').css('outline-color', 'none');$('#privacy_check').css('outline-style', 'none');$('#privacy_check').css('outline-width', '0');
```

Comment: ternary operator, evaluates to a value. Do you want this to evaluate to some value?

Comment: Don't. It will simply make it more difficult to read to no advantage

Comment: ok, so maybe best to leave as a normal `if/else statement`. thanks!

Comment: *"Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand"* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522828/is-code-for-computers-or-for-people

Comment: fair point @Liam. having said that vaclavs answer below refactors my code from 9 lines to 4... that is good too right?

Comment: But why? What is loosing those 5 lines saving you? Is it more efficient, no (not in processing time). Is it easier to read, no. Does it effect the processing of the code at all, no. So why change it? If you want to reduce your download times (FYI) you should look into using minification, something like [YUI](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/)

Comment: @Liam I do agree with everything you said above, but at the same time there is an attitude out that less lines of code required to complete a task is better. Perhaps I have been taught incorrectly but I always believe lots of `if/else` statements is bad if there is a more clever way of doing things. Perhaps this example isn't perfect, but i do believe that attitude exists out there

Comment: If there is code review, please let us know how this ternary operator is appreciated.

Comment: @thefourtheye will do! do you also believe that it should be avoided?

Comment: I would say, your current code looks okay. Its more readable. There is no obvious advantage by using ternary operator in this case.

Comment: @thefourtheye ok, I appreciate what you are saying, but in that case could you advise when there would be an obvious advantage in using a ternary operator?

Comment: Maybe something like this http://ideone.com/kFVMvK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $elem = $('#privacy_check');
$elem.css($elem.is(':checked') ?
    { outlineColor: 'none', outlineStyle: 'none', outlineWidth: 0 } :
    { outlineColor: 'red', outlineStyle: 'solid', outlineWidth: 'thin' })
```

Answer (score 4):

Simplify.

CSS:

```css
#privacy_check {
    outline: thin solid red;
}
#privacy_check:checked {
    outline: none;
}
```

No JavaScript required.

Comment: Ok but he was asking for a javascript-based solution O.o

Comment: sorry, you must have misunderstood the question. I only want to show the red if it is not checked

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol i have prob not provided enough info in the question to be fair. I only want to show the red after an attempt is made to submit the form

Comment: Sounds like you want `<input type="checkbox" required />` coupled with `#privacy_check:invalid {outline: thin solid red;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
$('#privacy_check').change(function() {
  $(this).css({
    'outline-color': this.checked ? 'none' : 'red',
    'outline-style': this.checked ? 'none' : 'solid',
    'outline-width': this.checked ? '0' : 'thin'
  });
}).change()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="privacy_check" />
```

---

More simplified as ***@Rayon*** suggested

```js
$('#privacy_check').change(function() {
  $(this).css("outline", this.checked ? 'none' : "thin solid red")
}).change()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="privacy_check" />
```

Comment: Consider `$("#privacy_check").css("outline", "thin solid red");`..I guess it will reduce redundant code..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $elem = $('#privacy_check');

if($elem.is(":checked")){
    $elem.css("outline", "thin solid red");
}
else{
   $elem.css("outline", "none");
}
```

Comment: You put `$('#privacy_check') into a variable but didn't use it :D I fixed it for you.